# Embedding image data inline html

Tags: php, html, data-uri

I'm trying to embed an image with it's data inline.however when I don't encode my data as `base64` it doesn't work and some random characters are displayed.here are the two variations in php:

```
....
//$img-->image data read from database
$data = stream_get_contents($img);
$data64 = base64_encode($data);//when I don't use this it doesn't work

$image64 = '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.$data64.'>';
$image = '<img src="data:image/jpeg,'.$data.'>';
```

`$img64` works but `$img' doesn't.what's the problem?

Answer (score 2):

That's to be expected. JPEG data will naturally contain `>` and `"` and other HTML metacharacters. As soon as a `"` and then `>` are encounter, your browser will think the `<img>` tag has been closed, and everything else will be treated as text

e.g, if you don't base64_encode, you'll get something like

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg,randomgarbagewitha"andthena>andsome more random garbage">
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                               the binary contents of the jpg here
                                            ^--end of src attribute
                                                     ^---end of img tag
```